# Old computer Intel Sound Card cannot work with Ubuntu

Tags: sound, hardware

I tried everything.

My sound card is

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

I tried commands and rebooting and everything, it just DOES NOT WORK.
Just no sound, at all.

What to do?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

No questions on the forum could answer this, I tried the solutions of downgrading, everything, how do I fix the sound?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is not enough information here to offer any suggestions. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're using (1) the complete Terminal output of `sudo lspci` (2) more details about what you've tried (so that the same suggestions are not made). With this, it *might* be possible for someone to offer an answer 

Answer (score 1):

it might be possible that you need to install pavucontrol and check if thr device is configured properly and detected in pavucontrol.

Run `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

Then open it and check the output and configuration tab. (I had to reconnect my sound output device to a new jack, you might have to unmute the sound output as well)

Comment: I just did what you said. No sound unfortunately.

Comment: WTF should I do to get sound from this system?!